# How to make surface plot with table of x y z values in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly, rgl

I have a table of data like this in a dataframe: https://gofile.io/d/JdfbJ8

It is of the following form

```
      x                 y             z

-4.0965350229   3.3847132724    0
-1.9223487932   -12.7011913854  2.5830465849
-1.0243678647   2.4912755441    0
10.6878888053   -2.3297447759   0
-3.4455955583   9.6275811594    0
-3.3292306024   1.8922311466    0
-3.8718317109   4.1021886271    0
-3.3064902383   4.1589992445    0
-5.4794543344   4.6003308695    2.1796417068
11.3829161566   -3.5274643499   2.3091816018
-2.2049551565   -12.6093058187  1.2683356585
```

What I want to do is use it to make a surface plot that looks like this:https://plotly.com/r/3d-surface-plots/

using a function like plotly or persp3d that already have a lot of functionality.

The only problem is that they seem to require what the data be in a matrix of integer values that covers the entire grid.

(i.e. data[4][5] would be the z-value for x = 4, y = 5)

I would really appreciate some help in how to use my data to generate a surface plot like the one I need.

Comment: you have negative coordinates, but you want to fit them on a surface plot, where would the z values with negative coordinates appear?

Comment: If there were, then they would go below the xy-plane (i.e. at negative z values)..However, in my data, the z-coordinates are all >=0.